# Using variable in setState - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that similar questions were asked before, but what if i don't want to set the entire state, only one of its properties, to a variable? Something like this:

```js
var initialProperty = {
  name: '',
  id: 0,
  type: ''
}

class Example extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      otherProperty: '',
      targetProperty: initialProperty
      //at the start of the Component, everything works fine.
      //the targetproperty is set to initialproperty
    }
  }
  //by the time, the targetproperty was changed from the initial in the component
  //but if i click a button, i want to set targetproperty to the initialproperty
  somethingHappensOnClick = () => {
    this.setState({targetProperty: initialProperty})
    //unfortunately, the targetproperty wasn't set to the initial.
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why `targetProperty` doesn't change?

Comment: *Why targetProperty don't change*, can you show how you are checking that?

Comment: Because if the targetProperty changes to inital, the whole app's style is changing. But mine isn't change.

Comment: show your render method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because, in js array and object get copied by reference. So when you are setting

```
targetProperty: initialProperty
```

`targetProperty` will get the reference of `initialProperty`, and all the changes that you will do to `targetProperty`, will get applied to `initialProperty` as well.

Idea is, create a new object each time, instead of copying the reference.

Write it like this:

```
var initialProperty = {
  name: '',
  id: 0,
  type: ''
}

class Example extendds React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      otherProperty: '',
      targetProperty: Object.assign({}, initialProperty) // or {...initialProperty}
    }
  }

  somethingHappensOnClick = () => {
    this.setState({targetProperty: Object.assign({}, initialProperty)})
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. What i'm thinking about, is that i have a function in my code which also affects the `targetProperty` (named here). In my code, I have an input field, and two buttons. If the input field changes, it calls a function which sets the this.state.targetproperty.name with:
    `this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.targetProperty, {name: event.target.value}))`. And the `somethingHappensOnclick is called when the user clicks on any of the two buttons, reseting the targetproperty. It's possible that the onchange and onclick conflitcs with each other?

Answer (score 1):

When you are setting `targetProperty : initialProperty` what happens is

```
initialProperty--->some_memory_location_x
//after doing targetProperty: initialProperty
targetProperty---->some_memory_location_x
```

so when you are mutating the `targetProperty` you are actually changing the values in the memory `some_memory_location_x` which is where your `initialProperty` is also pointing at so when you setState again, your `targetProperty` value doesn't change so try doing the way @Mayank Shukla Pointed out so that you don't mutate values